# Guava Function with generic types

Tags: java, generics, guava

I am trying to code up a few `Function`s that I will be using quite often in the rest of my code. Some of these are things like, say, summing up all the numbers of an `Iterable`. Instead of implementing different functions for `Double`, `Integer`, etc. I want a single Function that sums up all the elements of a given Iterable *as long as each element is a number*. In order to do this, I attempted the following:

```
<T> Function<List<T extends Number>, T> sum = new Function<List<T extends Number>, T>() {
    public T apply(List<T> tlist) {
        // the main code
    }
};
```

But I get a compiler error saying "Unexpected token". I have coded my own Java methods with generics before, but I don't understand why the same thing isn't working here. Am I missing something ridiculously obvious, or is it that guava Functions don't allow generics?

Comment: Returning `Double` in the `apply()` method was a typing mistake, corrected it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple things:

1. If you're going to define bounds for a generic type (e.g. `T extends Number`) you have to do it where the type is declared (e.g. not `<T> Function...` but `<T extends Number> Function...`). I see Louis has already covered this.
2. I'm not sure it's really possible to implement a single function that can sum any type of `Number`, though you could come reasonably close I suppose. You'd have to take into consideration the possibility of numbers that are larger than any of the built in primitive types can represent (`BigInteger`, `BigDecimal`, and even possibly custom `Number` subclasses).
3. Your method doesn't really need to a type parameter at all if your function returns `Double`.

It can just be:

```
Function<List<? extends Number>, Double> sum = new Function<List<? extends Number, Double>() {
  public Double apply(List<? extends Number> numbers) {
    // the main code
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the *large* number classes. Hadn't thought of those at all.

Comment: Just wanted to share that I resorted to writing different functions for Double, Integer, etc. The single-method for anything extending `Number` was leading to an ugly list of `instanceof` statements ... and that defeats the entire purpose of what I was trying to achieve: brevity in my code.

Answer (score 1):

You can't define a polymorphic *variable* like this, and you can also only put bounds like `extends Number` inside the initial declaration of the `T` type variable.  I suspect that the closest thing  to what you mean that would actually work is something like

```
<T extends Number> Function<List<T>, T> sum() {
  return new Function<List<T>, T>() {
    public Double apply(List<T> doubles) {
        // the main code
    }
  };
}
```

...except that you're also going to have issues returning a `Double` instead of a `T`.